# Why is there no secular/liberal/libertarian parties in Indonesia?

Tags: libertarianism, indonesia

In the US, the Libertarian Party has few seats because of the winner-takes-all election.

However, in Indonesia, there is no winner-takes-all election.

You can go to the local DPRD (regional parliament) and if you get 10% of the vote, you get 10% of the seats.

Why aren't there libertarian, secular, or liberal parties in Indonesia?

For example,

Any political party in Indonesia wants to modify KUHP 156? Legalize porn, prostitution, and drugs? Any party wants to eliminate income tax? Or at least push them to province issues?

Surely there are more than 1% of Indonesians that want those. Yet almost no parties say they would do so.

Comment: Depending on your definition of secular and liberal, one could argue that there **are** such parties in Indonesia. I think a libertarian party would have a lot of difficulties to convince anyone in a developping country. And even in the US, libertarians must still be quite far from getting 10% of the votes...

Comment: Golkar is a major party that is Secular, capitalist and "neo-liberal" http://carnegieendowment.org/2013/10/24/indonesia-s-political-parties-pub-53414  As such your question is unclear, as secular and captitalist parties do exist.

Comment: Indonesia isn't a democracy in the ordinary sense. Also a lot of atheists were seen as communists and killed in the Indonesian mass killings of 1965–66.

Answer (score 3):

Indonesian politics are complex. To start with is there no traditional left vs right wing. The parties and political candidates are all over the place. Generally pro-worker, Islam, nationalistic, strong government to varying degrees, depending on the time of the day or election cycle.

One could argue that Indonesian left wing would include neo-socialist/Marxist with moderate nationalism, e.g. Jokowi and right wing with strong man, military, heavy nationalism and strong Islam influences.

Libertarian ideas are lost in all this. 99.999999% percent of Indonesian would not have a clue what it stands for, or even know who John Locke was.

Having said that, many young educated Indonesians are interested in Libertarian concepts. Many are tired of the failing overbearing state, religious influence, curbs on personal freedom and "decent".

So there are little seeds of Libertarianism in Indonesian's fertile political soil. Given some time...

Comment: Electric cycles? Also it will be great if you give some sources  to support your arguments.